# How to design whatsapp chat bubble in android studio?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to create a chatting application. So i want a **chat Bubble design**

> I'm interested in chat bubble design of whatsapp...

Comment: welcome to stack overflow ? what have you tried so far ? this community isn't a free coding service, so please show us what you've done or tried so far :D also, what does this question have to do with firebase?

Comment: Okay, good to know. Good luck in that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a png image of your desire chat bubble then use android studio 9patch tool to convert that png to 9 patch image. For png chat bubble image, talk with your designer to make this for your. Or you can get sample chat bubble from internet but that one may be not as you expected, better to take from your any designer.

To know more about 9 patch image follow below link :
[9patch image](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/draw9patch)